# Time series object with multiple station data with different time periods?

Tags: r, time-series, trend, data-preprocessing

How can make a time series object from a set of data. I have data set from a number of regional meteorological stations. And I don't know how to create a time series object that includes time series data from different meteorological stations. My data has following structure 
, indicates csv file like structure for understanding)
. indicates several different data
X1,x2, x3 xn and y1,y2 y3 yn indicate different values
stationId: Each station has a unique ID number (That I want to use is as a categorical value)

```
Nu, StationID, Year, MeanTemp, MaxTemp
1,  1001     , 1950,   x1     , y1
2,  1001     , 1951,   x2     , y2
3,  1001     , 1952,   x3     , y3
.,  1001     ,   . ,   xi     , yi
.,  1001     ,   . ,   xi+1   , yi+1    
50, 1001     , 2000,   x50    , y50
51, 1002     , 1970,    .     ,  .  
52, 1002     , 1971
.,  .        , 1972 
.,  .        , 1973
80, 1002     , 2000 
81, 1003     , 1960
84, 1003     , 1961
.,   .       ,
```

etc.
My question is: Is it possible to create a time series object;
that have more then one meteorological station data
where stations may have different number of collected data (one -say- 50 year-long but the other has 40 the third one is 60)

The problem is I have more then 250 stations, spanning different years, and have 11 different climate data: Rainfall,  temperature, snow fall, freezing days etc.
I want to create a loop code to repeat the same analyses for different climate station with respect to changes in the station ID. first I need to solve this time series object problem.

Comment: This is what the tsibble package is designed for. See https://tsibble.tidyverts.org.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I'll try it